# Cannot obtain the application id some one know how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-emulator

the app is not working in the emulator
when i try i got this message

Run configuration app is not supported
in the current projet.
Cannot obtain the application id

I reinstalled android

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean Project - **Build -> Clean project**
2. Rebuild project  - **Build -> Rebuild project**
3. Invalidate Cache  - **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart**